# Asset File not found on android but on pc Build - libGDX

Tags: android, libgdx

I've got another question. I'm currently working on my next game and I encountered a big problem.

I can load my level description file via custom AssetLoader, but only if I compile for PC. On Android I got the "File not found Exception".

The File is :

`assets/levels/merkur/level1.gbl`

As mentioned, on PC I can load the file, on android not. I've tried every hint I found on google, rebuild, sync asset folder, renamed the file, but nothing works.

With

```
if (Gdx.files.internal("levels/merkur/level1.gbl").file().exists())
```

I got true for PC and false for android.

EDIT:

the assetmanager call :

```
assetManager.load(Gdx.files.internal("levels/merkur/level1.gbl").path(), MissionLoader.class, new XMLMissionAssetLoader.MissionParameters());
assetManager.load(Gdx.files.internal("levels/merkur/level2.gbl").path(),MissionLoader.class,new XMLMissionAssetLoader.MissionParameters());
```

My custom loader :

```
public class XMLMissionAssetLoader extends AsynchronousAssetLoader<MissionLoader, XMLMissionAssetLoader.MissionParameters> {
MissionLoader missionLoader;
public XMLMissionAssetLoader(FileHandleResolver resolver) {
    super(resolver);
}

@Override
public void loadAsync(AssetManager manager, String fileName, FileHandle file, MissionParameters parameter) {
    this.missionLoader = null;
    this.missionLoader = new MissionLoader(fileName);
}

@Override
public MissionLoader loadSync(AssetManager manager, String fileName, FileHandle file, MissionParameters parameter) {
    this.missionLoader = null;
    this.missionLoader = new MissionLoader(fileName);
    return missionLoader;
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@Override
public FileHandle resolve(String fileName) {
    return super.resolve(fileName);
}

@Override
public Array<AssetDescriptor> getDependencies(String fileName, FileHandle file, XMLMissionAssetLoader.MissionParameters parameter) {
    return null;
}

public static class MissionParameters extends AssetLoaderParameters<MissionLoader>
{

}
```

}

EDIT2:

complete log of this error:

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /levels/merkur/level1.gbl: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
W/System.err:     at libcore.net.url.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:123)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:117)
W/System.err:     at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:183)
W/System.err:     at com.cptnroughnight.apps.galaxyblast.GameState.MissionLoader.loadXML(MissionLoader.java:56)
W/System.err:     at com.cptnroughnight.apps.galaxyblast.GameState.MissionLoader.<init>(MissionLoader.java:40)
W/System.err:     at com.cptnroughnight.apps.galaxyblast.GameState.XMLMissionAssetLoader.loadAsync(XMLMissionAssetLoader.java:25)
W/System.err:     at com.cptnroughnight.apps.galaxyblast.GameState.XMLMissionAssetLoader.loadAsync(XMLMissionAssetLoader.java:16)
W/System.err:     at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.call(AssetLoadingTask.java:70)
W/System.err:     at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.call(AssetLoadingTask.java:34)
W/System.err:     at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.async.AsyncExecutor$2.call(AsyncExecutor.java:58)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
W/System.err:  ... 15 more
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /levels/merkur/level1.gbl: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
W/System.err:     at libcore.net.url.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:123)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:117)
W/System.err:     at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:183)
W/System.err:     at com.cptnroughnight.apps.galaxyblast.GameState.MissionLoader.loadXML(MissionLoader.java:56)
W/System.err:     at com.cptnroughnight.apps.galaxyblast.GameState.MissionLoader.<init>(MissionLoader.java:40)
W/System.err:     at com.cptnroughnight.apps.galaxyblast.GameState.XMLMissionAssetLoader.loadSync(XMLMissionAssetLoader.java:31)
W/System.err:     at com.cptnroughnight.apps.galaxyblast.GameState.XMLMissionAssetLoader.loadSync(XMLMissionAssetLoader.java:16)
W/System.err:     at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.handleAsyncLoader(AssetLoadingTask.java:125)
W/System.err:     at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.update(AssetLoadingTask.java:90)
W/System.err:     at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.updateTask(AssetManager.java:504)
W/System.err:     at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.update(AssetManager.java:378)
W/System.err:     at com.cptnroughnight.apps.galaxyblast.GalaxyBlast.render(GalaxyBlast.java:243)
W/System.err:     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onDrawFrame(AndroidGraphics.java:459)
W/System.err:     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1648)
W/System.err:     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1353)
W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
W/System.err:  ... 16 more
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /levels/merkur/level2.gbl: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
W/System.err:     at libcore.net.url.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:123)
W/System.err:     at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:117)
W/System.err:     at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:183)
W/System.err:     at com.cptnroughnight.apps.galaxyblast.GameState.MissionLoader.loadXML(MissionLoader.java:56)
W/System.err:     at com.cptnroughnight.apps.galaxyblast.GameState.MissionLoader.<init>(MissionLoader.java:40)
W/System.err:     at com.cptnroughnight.apps.galaxyblast.GameState.XMLMissionAssetLoader.loadAsync(XMLMissionAssetLoader.java:25)
W/System.err:     at com.cptnroughnight.apps.galaxyblast.GameState.XMLMissionAssetLoader.loadAsync(XMLMissionAssetLoader.java:16)
W/System.err:     at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.call(AssetLoadingTask.java:70)
W/System.err:     at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.call(AssetLoadingTask.java:34)
W/System.err:     at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.async.AsyncExecutor$2.call(AsyncExecutor.java:58)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: **Android file-system is case sensitive**, so make sure file-name/path is exact same.

Comment: I work on linux, so the filename/path is correct! But thanks :)

Comment: `The File is :

assets/levels/merkur/level1.gbl`. That is a relative path. What would be the absolute path? Or where is asset directory on file system or where else?

Comment: the asset folder is the standard asset folder created by libgdx/android studio... I can load all png's, fonts, particle effects, models.. but my custom loader keeps crashing on android

Comment: What is the value of `Gdx.files.internal("levels/merkur/level1.gbl").path()`. That will be the absolute path i asked for i think.

Comment: If it is really an assets manager you should use it like `assetManager.load("levels/merkur/level1.gbl")`.

Comment: Gdx.files.internal("levels/merkur/level1.gbl").path() will be this : "I/System.out: /levels/merkur/level1.gbl" I've also tried "assetManager.load("",Missionloader.class); I also check if the file exists. I don't know.. is android studio copying everything in the assets folde to the device, or is there some sort of differencing?

Comment: Well google for reading file from assets or copy file from assets. Then you see how it is normally done. I dont know how libgdx differs. And moreover it is pretty unclear which code is executed if you call assetManager.load(). And you did not explain what assetManager is. Anyhow the filename is treated as if it was for a file on file system. The path is wrong as such a path does not exist on the file system. Instead the assets folder (in your IDE) becomes a resource in an .apk file. At runtime the file has to be extracted from the apps apk using the assets manager.

Comment: It looks as if you are not using one. And i cannot follow your code. Its pretty unclear which statement gives the FileNotFoundException. You should of course have told that right in the beginning.

Comment: the path cannot be wrong, i load several models, png's, fonts in the same way and there are no problems. On PC build there are no errors, only on android. Either way, with Gdx.file.internal and without it, no change.     "Gdx.files.internal("levels/merkur/level1.gbl").file().exists()" gives me true on PC and false on android, working directory is on both platforms the same.

Comment: This is unrelated, but you should not be creating your object in both loadSync and loadAsync. Both of thesr methods are always called during the loading process.

Comment: Avoid using File objects on Android. They will not work properly. .exists() will always be false. The path with not be an absolute path either. Try to use the LibGDX FileHandle class directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are most likely not using the filename correct in your `MissionLoader` class. The filename is relative to where the file is stored, in this case `Gdx.files.internal`. This would be typically inside the APK on Android or inside the JAR when releasing for desktop. Since you are probably debugging on desktop (and not packaging to JAR), it likely works for you by accident on that platform.

You cannot simply use the filename without taking into consideration the type of storage. Likewise, you cannot assume the file to be a physical file on your os file system. Instead use the `FileHandle` supplied, which contains all information you need including read methods and such. For more information about this, see the wiki: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/File-handling.

Btw, you didn't include the correct code snippet. The correct snippet would be the part of the `com.cptnroughnight.apps.galaxyblast.GameState.MissionLoader.loadXML` method,
 around `line 56` of the `MissionLoader.java` file. You can look at your stacktrace for such information.

Also note that libgdx comes with its own XML reader/writer, which you might want to look into. See also: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Reading-and-writing-XML.

Answer (score 0):

If you load from assets in your Android app you will never get a FileNotFoundException if the file does not exist. Instead you get an IOException.

As you did not post the relevant code of your custom class there is little we can do.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks to all.. I've figured it out. It was indeed the wrong usage of the file handling. I also switched to libGDX XML-parser and it works great!

Sometimes I'm not able to see the woods for the trees!